# Flask works locally, but not on a server?

Tags: python, flask, server, client

I am developing a Flask application, that at the moment takes requests and answers them. However I developed it locally and it works just fine, but when trying to run it on `repl.it`, it doesn't work (Requests raises "Winerror 10060":

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`)

Why is that? (I know, that `repl.it` uses a different IP than I use locally, but I switched them already.)

client:

```
import json
import requests

conv = [{'id': 1, 'key': 'get_password'}]
payload = json.dumps(conv)
res = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000", json=payload).json()
print(res)
```

server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def home():
    jsondata = request.get_json()
    data = json.loads(jsondata)

    #stuff happens here that uses the data

    print(data)

    result = {'response': True}
    return json.dumps(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000)
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a helpful error description.

Comment: Edited the error message

Comment: Does it give error everytime you try to make request. If not then Check your internet connection. Also it is good to use named parameter `app.run(host"0.0.0.0", port=5000)`

Comment: Yes it does give the error, my internet works fine. I think it might be something like proxy or Firewall (at repl.it) that blocks the connection, but I don't know cases where this happened. Named parameters are edited.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are making request on address `127.0.0.1` which in case is not used by repl.it.

Make a request on the url provided by repl.it.

The url will be:

```
https://your-app-name.your-replit-username.repl.co/
```

Your code would be

```py
import json
import requests

conv = [{'id': 1, 'key': 'get_password'}]
payload = json.dumps(conv)
res = requests.post("https://moneyserver.jgroeger.repl.co/", json=payload).json()
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can establish a connection now. But now ```client.py``` gives: ```<Response:[404]>``` after removing the ```.json()``` at ```res = requests.post("https://address.example/", json=payload)```

Comment: Why have you removed `.json()` also you can check the logs in repl.it to see what is going on and why it gave 404 error. I don't know if is causing error but try adding extra slash in the url at end. `https://your-app-name.your-replit-username.repl.co/`

Comment: I removed ```.json()``` because ```client.py``` gave ```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)``` in line: ```res = requests.post("https://moneyserver.jgroeger.repl.co/:5000", data=payload).json()```

Comment: Why are you using `:5000` there is no need to use it there. This will surely give you 404 error. Your address should be only this `https://moneyserver.jgroeger.repl.co/`

Comment: I think bymistake you have the link above to your repl so I tried making the same request and I was able to get the result without any error. I edited the answer with the whole code I used.

Comment: Thanks man, that fixed it. Thpught i needed to use a port, but it seems, like there is no need for.